# Child div should be 100% in width

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to `slideDown()` child `div`, but the problem is parent div is `33.33%` in with and `position:relative` and I need children div which is `position:absolute`, should be 100% in width.

[This is](https://jsfiddle.net/m_zaid/n5k8awyo/1/) what I have done so far.

Below is the image which I want to achieve.
[image: I am sharing an image for reference what I actually want to achieve.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is noting in jsfiddle!

Comment: @AbhishekPandey check your internet connection fiddle is fine

Comment: Thread updated, btw this is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/m_zaid/n5k8awyo/1/)

Comment: It's not clear from the question what you are trying to acheive vs what you already have: "slideDown a div".  However, my first step would be to get rid of bootstrap grid - or at least move the member_detail divs to the next row

Answer (score 1):

you can use simply a plugin for this purpose. it will be more reliable with respect to compatibility. here is one for you http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

Comment: Thanks @rmarif for the help.